# Get page number of IndirectObject in ABCPdf

Tags: pdf, abcpdf

I have a script which processes indirect objects from the object soup (it processes the images of the PDF).

So, I have the `IndirectObject`, and I need the page number on which it is:

```
var indiObj = sourceDoc.ObjectSoup[objectToProcess];
```

I have tried to use `sourceDoc.GetInfo(indiObj.ID, "whatever");` but I have no idea which property to use as type, because I couldn't find any documentation of the list of possible properties.

Comment: What ABCPdf version you have?

Comment: 9 but I dont think it changed much In 10 ?

Answer (score 1):

I asked about the version because I'm working with version 7 :(

It's an interesting question (IMHO). I thought first that this could be useful:

```
 oDoc.ObjectSoup.Catalog.Pages.GetPageArray
```

But, altough you get the pages, you can't get the object soup for each page (at least in version 7) .....

So, maybe, you can try something like this, as PDF code in 'objects soup' it's order from top to botton:

```
    Dim oDoc As New WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Doc
    Using oDoc
        oDoc.Read(path_to_your_PDF)

        Dim iPage As Integer = 0
        Dim sType As String

        For iAux As Integer = 0 To oDoc.ObjectSoup.Count - 1
            sType = oDoc.ObjectSoup(iAux).GetType.ToString()
            Select Case sType
                Case "WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Objects.Page"
                    iPage += 1
                    Debug.Print(vbNewLine & "Page " & iPage.ToString & " detected")
                Case "WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Objects.PixMap"
                    Dim oPDFImg As WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Objects.PixMap
                    oPDFImg = CType(oDoc.ObjectSoup(iAux), WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Objects.PixMap)
                    Debug.Print(vbNewLine & "Image on page " & iPage.ToString & " -> ID " & oPDFImg.ID.ToString)
            End Select
        Next
    End Using
```

You can use a "typeof" instead of that Select Case (change 'ABCpdf7' to 'ABCpdf9', anyway). Hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll try it when I can. Thanks !